# Testing view helpers

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, helper

I'm currently working on a Rails plugin used for generating iPhone specific HTML meta-tags. I'm trying to use ActionView::TestCase for unit tests but keep getting the same error. See file contents and error below. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

**test_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'active_support'
require 'action_view'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib', 'iphone_helper')
```

**iphone_test_helper.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class IphoneHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test 'br' do
    tag = tag('br')
    assert_tag_in tag, '<br />'
  end
end
```

**error**

```
RuntimeError: In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: OKay, this might be a stupid question, probably is, but did you try adding the include line it gives in the error message?

Comment: Yes I've tried adding the line which gave me another error `uninitialized constant IphoneHelperTest::Rails`

Comment: Ok, just guessing, but perhaps the url_helpers line needs to be included in test-helper instead of the individual test-case?

Comment: isn't that error telling you to put that line in your plugin?  What rails version? what ruby are you using? is this inside a rails app already, or are you testing this on it's own in it's own directory only without being in a rails app?

Answer (score 4):

Awful and hacky workaround that worked for me (since I am working on a gem and not in a full rails environment):

```
require 'ostruct'

module ActionController::UrlFor
  def _routes
    helpers = OpenStruct.new
    helpers.url_helpers = Module.new
    helpers
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to include [the respective Module](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet) in an old-fashioned way?:

```
include ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
```

If a `NameError` is raised telling you that ActionDispatch is unknown you might have to `require 'action_dispatch'`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question, but is the fact that the class name and the file name don't match possibly a problem (IphoneHelperTest vs. iphone_test_helper.rb)? Sometimes that leads to classes not being loaded.